# How can I cleanly print a web page to a Generic/Txt Printer?

Tags: php, web-applications, printing

I have an web application that generates a small receipt format. 
when printed to a generic/txt printer.. Nothing is printed to the sheet

Here is a sample of the print..
***Removed***

Please is there a way i could print this webpage to a generic/txt printer

Here is the html

```
        <style>
    body{
        font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;  
        font-size:13px;
    }
    .f1{
        text-transform:uppercase;
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .f2{
        text-transform:uppercase;
        display:block;
        margin-left:10px;
    }

    .border_bottom{
        border-bottom:2px dashed #000;
    }
    .border_top{
        border-top:2px dashed #000;
    }

    .body_table{
        border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;
        padding:.5em;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="window.print();">
    <table width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body_table">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="f1">Official Receipt</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="f1">DreamWorks Pharmaceutical Industries Limited GH.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="f1">Plot 14 Blk 8A</span></td>
        </tr> 
    <tr>
            <td class="border_bottom"><span class="f1">0241093621</span></td>
        </tr>   


    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">RECEIPT NO.: 0241093621</span></td>
        </tr>     

    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">VAT REG #.: </span></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">cashier.: </span></td>
        </tr> 

    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">date.:  time: </span></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td class="border_bottom"><span class="f2">customer.:  time: </span></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="98%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%"><span class="f2">QTY</span></td>
                    <td width="60%"><span class="f2">item</span></td>
                    <td width="15"><span class="f2">price</span></td>
                    <td width="15"><span class="f2">amt.</span></td>                
                </tr> 


                        <tr>
                        <td class="f2">52</td>
                        <td>MALAREX TABS</td>
                        <td>2.6</td>
                        <td>135.20</td>
                        </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="border_top border_bottom">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" id="print_table7"> 
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg" width="53%"><span>Subtotal</span></Td>
                        <td width="47%" align="right">135.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Discount</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>VAT</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Total Due</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">135.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Paid</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">135.20</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Change</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">0.00</td>
                    </tr>                                                
                 </table>
        </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
        <td>Thank You dear customer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>VAT Inclusive Where Applicable</td>
    </tr>                           
    </table>
    </body>
```

Here's the Receipt Format HTML

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @media screen{
        body{
            font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;  
            font-size:13px;
        }
        .f1{
            text-transform:uppercase;
            display:block;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .f2{
            text-transform:uppercase;
            display:block;
            margin-left:10px;
        }

        .border_bottom{
            border-bottom:2px dashed #000;
        }
        .border_top{
            border-top:2px dashed #000;
        }

        .body_table{
            border:1px dashed #CCCCCC;
            padding:.5em;
        }   
    }

    @media print{
        body{
            font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;  
            font-size:8px;
            width:250px;
        }
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="window.print();">
    <table width="300" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body_table">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="f1">Official Receipt</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="f1">DreamWorks Pharmaceutical Industries Limited GH.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="f1">Plot 14 Blk 8A</span></td>
        </tr> 
    <tr>
            <td class="border_bottom"><span class="f1">0241093621</span></td>
        </tr>   


    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">RECEIPT NO.: 0241093621</span></td>
        </tr>     

    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">VAT REG #.: </span></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">cashier.: </span></td>
        </tr> 

    <tr>
            <td class=""><span class="f2">date.:  time: </span></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
            <td class="border_bottom"><span class="f2">customer.:  time: </span></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="98%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%"><span class="f2">QTY</span></td>
                    <td width="60%"><span class="f2">item</span></td>
                    <td width="15"><span class="f2">price</span></td>
                    <td width="15"><span class="f2">amt.</span></td>                
                </tr> 


                        <tr>
                        <td class="f2">6</td>
                        <td>MALAREX TABS</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td class="f2">1</td>
                        <td>PARAFEN PLUS TAB.</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td class="f2">5</td>
                        <td>ASTHAX INHALER</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="border_top border_bottom">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" id="print_table7"> 
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg" width="53%"><span>Subtotal</span></Td>
                        <td width="47%" align="right">25.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Discount</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>VAT</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Total Due</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">25.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Paid</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">25.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <Td class="ash_backg"><span>Change</span></Td>
                        <td align="right">0.00</td>
                    </tr>                                                
                 </table>
        </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
        <td>Thank You dear customer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>VAT Inclusive Where Applicable</td>
    </tr>                           
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How are you printing the sheet?

Comment: @Daniel Im Printing from firefox.. CTRL + P Generic Printer is the Default the  output is just few dark dots and thats all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS media types. Use one for the screen to make it look nice and one for print, to make it plain.

For example:

```
@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
  }
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
```

Comment: is it advisable to use the table in the receipt.. does the generic/text printer supports it?

Comment: i doubt it will support tables. Just basic ascii characters I believe is the norm.

Comment: ive tried this all.. but it doesnt work.. it keeps printing few dots from the printer.. I tried printing the same contents from notepad.. and it prints correctly.. Could my browser be sending something the printer doesnt understand?

Comment: html tags? Maybe you can have a print button that opens up a new tab/window with a plain text file, use header("Content-Type: text/plain"); and dont have any html tags at all.

Comment: Finally Opera was able to print the generic text clearly.. Even with html formatting Firefox and Google chrome didn't help thnx alot

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can print the document as the above and you have to use the separate style sheet for the screen display and printing. CSS rules are:

```
@media screen
  {
  //Css
  }

@media print{
    @page { size:250px 375px; margin: 4px }
    body{font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;  font-size:8px;}
    .f1{text-transform:uppercase; display:block; text-align:center;}
    .f2{text-transform:uppercase; display:block; margin-left:10px;}
    .border_bottom{ border-bottom:2px dashed #000;}
    .border_top{border-top:2px dashed #000;}
    .body_table{border:1px dashed #CCCCCC; padding:.5em;}
}
```

In these you can describe the page size, colors and many more things Just Google the CSS Print specification and you would know more.

But, I think the another problem involved in your i.e. print using POS printer to print it. For that I would Like to suggest the way are:

Two simple ways to do it, depending on how much interference you're willing to accept in your interface.

Firstly, you can just use JavaScript to trigger your receipt page/iframe to print. This option is a little klunky, as it requires the cashier to confirm the print in the system dialogue.

But secondly, you always have the option of sharing each station's printer on the network. Your server-side component can print directly to it. And if it's a *nix server, it's pretty easy to do once each station's printer has added to / shared with the server. In PHP (with CUPs installed, I imagine):

```
// attempt to pipe to 'lp -d printername'
if (`echo "{$text}" | lp -d {$printer_name}`) {
    // print successful
    return true;
} else {
    // print failed
    return false;
}
```

For second method, If you're running a windows server, it's probably much more complicated.

Comment: is it advisable to use the table in the receipt.. does the generic/text printer supports it?

Comment: yes it supports but i will advice to use div as create table through css as it would make sure printing at exact point

Comment: do i need to change the encoding in the html headers?

Comment: ive tried this all.. but it doesnt work.. it keeps printing few dots from the printer.. I tried printing the same contents from notepad.. and it prints correctly.. Could my browser be sending something the printer doesnt understand?

Comment: ive edited my post to include the full html for the receipt printer format

Comment: Finally Opera was able to print the generic text clearly.. Firefox and Google chrome didn't help thnx alot